# Maximum difference between MORE than two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Can someone help me with this?
It is to perform a query in SQL on a REDSHIFT database. The table has the data loaded as follows.
A client, for example, has a date field that determines her activity in an application:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| customer_1 | 2019-01-18 |
| customer_1 | 2019-08-25 |
| customer_1 | 2020-02-25 |
| customer_1 | 2020-06-18 |
| customer_2 | 2019-08-21 |
| customer_2 | 2020-02-13 |
| customer_2 | 2020-06-30 |
| customer_3 | 2020-01-18 |
| customer_3 | 2020-04-04 |

I need to group by client and know their MAXIMUM period of inactivity. I call MAXIMUM inactivity the longest period between TWO dates in which it did not interact. To do this with SQL, you should go through all the dates of the same user (customer_x) which is PK.
I do not know if you can help me think about it since I have not been able to do it alone. Thanks.

| ID | Maximum inactivity (in days) |
| --- | --- |
| customer_1 | 94 |
| customer_2 | 60 |
| customer_3 | 45 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG()` for this.

For example:

```
select
  id,
  max(inactivity) as max_inactivity
from (
  select
    id,
    datediff(day, lag(date) over(partition by id order by date), date)
      as inactivity
  from t
) x
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this solution**

**Details**

```
SELECT  T1.ID, 
    T1.Date As Date1, 
    MIN(T2.Date) AS Date2, 
    DATEDIFF(day, T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) AS inactive_days
FROM    YourTable T1
    LEFT JOIN YourTable T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID
        AND T2.Date > T1.Date
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Date
Order By ID,Date1
```

[image]

**Desired Results**

```
SELECT a.ID,MAX(a.inactive_days) AS [Maximum inactivity (in 
days)]
FROM
(SELECT  T1.ID, 
    T1.Date As Date1, 
    MIN(T2.Date) AS Date2, 
    DATEDIFF(day, T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) AS inactive_days
    FROM YourTable T1
    LEFT JOIN YourTable T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID
        AND T2.Date > T1.Date
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Date
) As a
GROUP BY a.ID
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to take note that the OP supplied expected results and... your results don't match. If you read the question carefully, you'll see the maximum being sought is the *difference* between successive dates, not the maximum period covering *all* of the dates.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for the comment. I'll update my query.